# Flash banner not linking

Tags: flash, actionscript

I was following this tutorial http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Full-flash-Banner/20583 and I wanted to add links to pictures shown within the banner. So I've edited 'picture 1/2/3' in the library panel transforming them into movie clips, and then opened them in edit mode and added required actionscript. But when I publish/preview them, they're not linking. I'm getting a clickable mouse-cursor over my banner, bun nothing happens. What should I do to make it work ?

This is the actual project :

http://www.2shared.com/file/yQVtKjgz/200612314_FullFlashBanner.html

and here's the code I'm adding :

```
on (release) {
getURL ("my link here","_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please give more details, what code did you add? test your mouse events with a trace() statement, that may give you some form of idea of what's missing.